# Firebase Storage Admin Error:400 Invalid Bucket Name

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I'm trying to use firebase functions to do maintenance of my database and storage. Basically remove some old entries from one ref/bucket to another after they expire.
The database part works great. However, the storage part, not so much. Here's how I initialize everything in my code:

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require('./my-app-bla-bla.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://my-app.firebaseio.com',
  storageBucket: 'gs://my-app.appspot.com'
});
```

Then in the cron job that cleans the database and storage, I have the following (this is only some small relevant part):

```
const st = admin.storage();

st.bucket("gs://my-app.appspot.com/old-listings/"+listingKey).create(function(error, bucket, apiResponse) {
    if (error) {
        console.log("Couldn't create an OldListing bucket: " + error.code);
        console.log(apiResponse);
    } else {
        console.log("Created OldListing bucket");
    }
});
```

This last piece of code triggers the error and gives me the following log:

```
Couldn't create an OldListing bucket: 400
{ error: 
   { errors: [ [Object] ],
     code: 400,
     message: 'Invalid bucket name: \'my-app.appspot.com/old-listings/SomeUniqueID\'' } }
```

Because I'm running this code for the first time, the folder `old-listings` does not exist yet. So I though maybe I should create its bucket on its own first. It gives me the same error.

I also tried using the buckets without the gs link, e.g. `st.bucket("old-listings/"+listingKey)` instead of `st.bucket("gs://my-app.appspot.com/old-listings/"+listingKey)`. Still gives me the same error.

so what exactly is missing here? What am I doing wrong?

## Edit 1

I tried adding the following code snippet at the beginning of my cron function. In an effort to better understand what's going on.

```
admin.storage().bucket("my-app.appspot.com").exists(function(error, exists) {
    if (!error) {
        if (exists) {
            console.log("Top Bucket Exists");
        } else {
            console.log("Top Bucket Does Not Exist");
        }
    } else {
        console.log("Top Bucket Error " + error.code);
    }
});

admin.storage().bucket("my-app.appspot.com/listings").exists(function(error, exists) {
    if (!error) {
        if (exists) {
            console.log("Listings Bucket Exists");
        } else {
            console.log("Listings Bucket Does Not Exist");
        }
    } else {
        console.log("Listings Bucket Error " + error.code);
    }
});
```

I get the following in my log:

```
Top Bucket Exists
Listing Bucket Error undefined
```

Of course I already have a folder called `listings` in my firebase storage. So why on earth would the second bucket be undefined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you build a name to a bucket, it's not supposed to contain file path components in it,  It should just be the unique name of the bucket - the container for all your objects.  If you want to reference a file in the bucket, use the [file()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/Bucket#file) method on the bucket object to get a [File](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/File#move) object to deal with.

```
const st = admin.storage();
const bucket = st.bucket('name-of-your-bucket');
const file = bucket.file('name-of-your-file');
```

Comment: So my understanding that a bucket is the same as a directory is wrong. It's one bucket for the whole thing. So that means a file has to be identified by its full path inside the bucket, for example "listings/name.png". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: But then what if I want to deal with directories in the storage, not files?

Comment: There are not really any "directories" in Cloud Storage.  There are just files with names that look like they contain directories, to help your mental model of the organization of files.  Notice that there is a lack of API for listing files within "directories", because directories don't exist.  There may be ability to list files within "directories" in the future, but there still won't actually be any directories, just new indexes of your files within your concept of a "directory".

Comment: Understood, that requires some changes in my code. Thanks a lot.